# What's the better way: 1 pipe and 1 socket, or 1 socket?

Tags: c, sockets, stream, two-way

I have a server-program which processes audio-data and passes it thru to the audio-drivers.

The server-program copies the audio-data and puts the copy in a named FIFO in a seconds thread.

If there is no client reading on the other side of the FIFO it does not matter, because it just blocks the FIFO-thread.

Now I would like to add a "control"-functionality like "increase volume, play faster etc." so the eventually connected client can control the server-program.

The important thing is: If the client eventually disconnects (through close() or abort) the server has detect this and should fall back into normal mode and forget all the commands from the client.

I have never used sockets until now, so I'm not sure what's the best way:

1. use the FIFO from server->client as it is and add a socket just for client->server communication?
2. use one socket to stream server->client and give commands from client->server (in byte-format?)

I would use "AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM" for the socket. Is #2 the better variant? And how can I determine if the client disconnected without a close()?

Comment: It's not uncommon to use multiple connections to do different things, see for example FTP. But you can also use the same connection to do different things, if the protocol allows for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i vote option nr.2 and a possible solution for that is:

1-create socket[sock_stream....];

2-fork()[inherits the socket descriptor];

```
-father[use to read];
-son[use to write];
```

**you can implement to detect a client disconnection when read() from socket descriptor returns 0bytes**

Comment: Okay, and the client does the same, yes? One thread/fork to receive the data and the other one to eventually write commands? Do you know how to determine if the client quits without proper close?

Comment: yes so it can be bi-directional on both, and it is possible to determine because when a read(from sock fd) returns 0 bytes means the other end was close aka disconnected